# pass variable from 1st window to any other(3rd,5th) window in titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-alloy

I need to get the variable from first window in titanium.

I have following the below code.but i didn't get the result.

**index.js**

```
 var  manager_id;
  function ManagerLogin(){ 
          if($.manager_email.value != "" && $.manager_email.value != null){ 

                 var request = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({ 
               onload : function(e) {
                manager_id= this.responseText;
       // Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
```

this manager_id value pass to another window . how can i do ?

I have written the code like.,

**sample.js**

```
   manager_id = Ti.index.manager_id;
  Ti.API.info(Ti.index.manager_id);
```

But i didn't get the value from index.js file..how can i get the value ? please check my code and give me a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using alloy then we usually use Alloy.Globals to store global variable so you use this to store value globaly.

```
  function ManagerLogin(){ 
          if($.manager_email.value != "" && $.manager_email.value != null){ 

                 var request = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({ 
               onload : function(e) {
                Alloy.Globals.manager_id= this.responseText;
```

so you can use it in your Sample.js file like below

```
manager_id = Alloy.Globals.manager_id;
  Ti.API.info(manager_id);
```